Problem with connecting my metamask to my dapp frontend
When I click on connect wallet button, my metamask wallet is opening and asking for permission to connect the wallet. However, even after I connect it, the application isn't showing that there is no account connected.
This is my components/ManualHeader.js file:

import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function Header() {
const { enableWeb3, account, isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis()
const \[isConnected, setIsConnected\] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("isWeb3Enabled:", isWeb3Enabled)
        console.log("account:", account)
        if (account && isWeb3Enabled) {
            setIsConnected(true)
        }
    }, [account, isWeb3Enabled])
    
    return (
        <div>
            {isConnected ? (
                <div>
                    Connected to {account.slice(0, 6)}...{account.slice(account.length - 4)}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <button
                    onClick={async () => {
                        try {
                            await enableWeb3()
                            console.log("Web3 Enabled")
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error("Failed to enable Web3:", error)
                        }
                    }}
                >
                    Connect Wallet
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    )

pages/ _app.js :

import Head from "next/head"
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
return (
\<\>
\<Head\>
\<title\>Smart Contract Lottery\</title\>
\<meta name="description" content="Our Smart Contract Lottery"\>\</meta\>
\</Head\>
\<MoralisProvider initializeOnMount={false}\>
\<Component {...pageProps} /\>
\</MoralisProvider\>
\</\>
)
}

My package.json:

{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"dependencies": {
"ethers": "^6.13.2",
"moralis-v1": "^1.13.0",
"next": "14.2.5",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"react-moralis": "^1.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"postcss": "^8",
"prettier": "^3.3.3",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
}
}


If anyone knows how to solve this, please help me with the issue. And also I'd appreciate if anyone suggest me a good alternate for react-moralis with connecting Web3 wallets in a React application.
